# How did Scientists Capture The First Images of Molecules Before and After Reaction?

Tags: spectroscopy

> Using a state-of-the-art atomic force microscope, the scientists have taken the first atom-by-atom pictures, including images of the chemical bonds between atoms, clearly depicting how a molecule's structure changed during a reaction. Until now, scientists have only been able to infer this type of information from spectroscopic analysis.  — [Source](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2013/05/130530142007.htm)

Are there any papers how this thing actually works?

Answer (score 5):

There are a ton of papers on how AFM works, but I'll have a go at explaining it anyhow.

Atomic Force Microscopy (AFM) is a venerable technology for imaging nanostructures down to individual molecules by physically contacting atoms on surfaces. The whole process is very similar to a finger reading Braille.

What does it mean to physically contact an atom? It means that the AFM works by detecting some kind of repulsion between an atom and a very, very sharp probe due to their respective electron clouds repelling. The forces between surfaces on the nanoscale are a complicated mixture of attraction due to Casimir-Polder/Van der Waals interactions, dipole-dipole interactions, electrostatic repulsion, Pauli exclusion, *etc. etc.*, but the key point is that if two objects get too close together they will experience a rapidly increasing repulsive interaction, which the AFM picks up.

This repulsion is detected through the deflection of a cantilever (a thin, long, elastic beam of material). The probe is mounted on the end of this cantilever, and the cantilever bends when the probe is pushed up against a substrate. The deflection of this cantilever is measured by bouncing a laser beam off the end, the change in position of the reflected beam indicating the force.

The AFM probe has an atomically sharp tip that can localise single atoms on a surface, and the tip is moved around using exquisitely precise actuators so that the tip can be scanned back and forth over a surface, picking up the bumps and valleys of the sample that indicate the positions of atoms. I've seen ads for AFM probes that actually have flared tips - these can obtain even more 3D information about nanostructures as they can hook into nanostructures from the side and measure the texture and relief parallel to the surface.

Comment: "There are a ton of papers on how AFM works" The clue in here is that you can see the chemical bounds.

Comment: @user8005 - What you are seeing is the molecular electron density. When two atoms are bonded, there is appreciable electron density between the atoms, and you can accentuate the appearance of distinct bonds through gradient mapping. Regrettably, I didn't read the article you linked which states that the technique used was ncAFM, which is a softer technique that doesn't push up against the sample but instead measures [modulation of resonance](http://www.ntmdt.com/spm-principles/view/non-contact-mode) in the cantilever, however the principle of measuring distance/force relationship is the same.